# How to query different mySQL databases with Prometheus for business monitoring

Tags: mysql, prometheus, grafana

Is it possible to monitor business data with prometheus which is stored in different mysql databases?

I want to create a dashboard with an alerting system in grafan cloud and get the data from prometheus. In order to connect prometheus to mysql I need a sql_exporter.

But where would I define the queries for my business monitoring?

Does this approach make any sense? If not, what else could I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use sql-agent, prometheus-sql, prometheus and grafana.

With sql-agent you can take the queries you want to monitor, formatted as JSON and execute them on database backend. From there you can use prometheus-sql to query your SQL database and parse these metrics to Prometheus. In Prometheus you can define alerts for your queries. Grafana is for visualization.

If your databases are in different servers, install prometheus-sql to each of them and target them from Prometheus.